# GIT merge successfully but introduce a compilation error

Tags: git

I have to find a situation where git merge the file successfully but there is an compilation error in the program after merging.

Is there any way to do that!!

I know git uses the longest common subsequence for merging.

I have done a lot of trial but not able to find.

If anyone know.... please help

Comment: These things can happen, don't worry. Just fix it, commit and move on with your life.

Comment: actually this happens with me once but i don't know how it happens..... please give me the situation so that i can safe me for the next time....

Comment: You actually didn't mentioned what is actually going wrong and how we can reproduce the problem. This makes the "question" unanswerable on a QA site. Therefore -1

Comment: Did you get any conflicts while merging? Did you resolve them correctly?

Comment: @actually It comes at a time.... I am also not able to find that situation now... that's why asking here.. is there any situation where this comes so that i can save me for the next time...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git merges can occasionally produce non-working code without any conflicts arising. Imagine the following:

- Developer A adds a call to function `foo` in the code he's working on.
- Developer B modifies function `foo`'s function signature, or renames/deletes the function.
- Developer A merges B's changes.

Now A's function call is incompatible with B's change, but git doesn't know that because they are in separate modules.

What A (you) should do in this case is review the changes that were merged in, and fix the code as appropriate. (This is also why you should keep feature branches short where possible, especially if you are trying to submit a patch upstream).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the merge introduced the error? Checkout the version before the merge and check if it compiles. If it doesn't find a commit that worked and have a look at the [bisect command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) to find the offending commit.

If the merge introduced the error you can diff the merge and the last working commit with [git diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) and look at the changes made by the merge.

Otherwise of course merging can sometimes introduce errors and bugs because it works on file content without unterstanding of the intention of the content. The only way around that is fixing it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform a merge, if you get conflicts, git will notify you about it. It's then up to the code maintainer to carefully resolve the conflicts.

For now, what you can do is a hard reset to the commit before the merge (the `HEAD` before you tried to merge) and then perform the merge again making sure you resolve the conflicts correctly this time.

Do a git log and get the last stable commit's id and then do a -

```
git reset --hard <commit id>
```

(You can also just revert the merge commit, but for now you can just reset the `HEAD`)

Now do the merge and resolve the conflicts. If you are working in a team, and if you are not particularly aware of your teammates' changes, it's better to gather them around and resolve the conflicts.

All the best.